# download indirect link file with visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, download

To download a file from internet using vb.net there is a couple of methods to make it works, but the problem is that some of links are having problem while downloading and i think problem is that links are not directly, so is there anyway to download file with indirect links thank you :)

Comment: have you tried WebClient ?

Comment: Do you have an example of one of these links? Using Fiddler or etc can you confirm your suspicion that the links are being redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpWebClient.AllowAutoRedirect` allows for automatic redirection. However, `AllowAutoRedirect` defaults to true, so you may need to look elsewhere in your code.